# Connecting to MySQL from local server slow

Tags: mysql, apache, lighttpd

I just started using git to manage my website's distribution. My site is running a lighttpd server and a Symfony 2 PHP framework. It connects to a remote MySQL server. When I cloned my project to my mac (running Apache), the site still works but it's extremely slow. The problem seems to be with the mysql connection. Performing just a few extra queries (10 or so) results in significantly longer page load time. The remote server that hosts my site runs just fine, it's way faster than my local copy.

What are some common causes of a slowdown like this?

Comment: your internet connection maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd take a look at the "just a few extra queries" to see if those are taking an unreasonable amount of time.

I'm assuming that you are still connecting to the remote MySQL server on your local copy? If this is the case the problem could be bandwidth. Rented servers are usually on 100Mbit+ connections, so the data transfer will be relatively quite compared to your broadband at home.

When your web app is running on your local copy try running a SHOW PROCESSLIST; on the MySQL Server.

Finally how powerful is your mac compared to the server? If you mac is underpowered and your trying to also run photoshop + illustrator + itunes etc etc this will make a difference.